# Обьединение 3х таблиц и агрегация

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть 3 таблицы - общага, комнаты и студенты.

Определенные комнаты привязаны до "общаги" (через HostelCode)

Студенты привязаны до таблицы "комнаты", в которой есть поле "вместимость студентов" - capacity.

Нужно вывести количество свободных мест в общаге. 
Нашел как вычислить общее количество, но как мне его использовать?
Вот запрос:

```
Select  Sum(Rooms.Capacity) AS Rooms
From Rooms
WHERE Rooms.HostelCode=1
```

Comment: если вы предоставите структуру таблиц, то это будет большой плюс качеству вопроса и повысит вероятность в решении его

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov добавил

Answer (score 4):

Можно так

```
SELECT SUM(Capacity) as AllC, c as Busy, (SUM(Capacity) - c) as Free from Rooms as Ro
INNER JOIN
(select Count(*) as c, r.RoomId as room
from Student as s
inner join Rooms as r On r.RoomId=s.RoomId && r.HostelCode=1
 ) as T On true 
 WHERE HostelCode=1
```

Ссылка на рабочий пример: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16f2ab/3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16f2ab/2)

Либо со вложенным запросом получается еще несколько короче:

```
SELECT SUM(Capacity) - (select Count(*)
from Student as s
inner join Rooms as r On r.RoomId=s.RoomId && r.HostelCode=1) 
from Rooms
WHERE HostelCode=1;
```

Ссылка на рабочий пример: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16f2ab/7

Answer (score 3):

Ответ на вопрос в заголовке: начиная с mySQL 8 появилась [конструкция With](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html), которая позволяет разбить текст SQL-запроса на логические части.

например,

```
with HostelCapacity (
    Select HostelCode, RoomId, sum(Rooms.Capacity) AS Capacity
    From Rooms
    group by HostelCode, RoomId
),
RoomsOccupied (
    Select HostelCode, Student.RoomId, count(*) as Occupied
    From Student
    Left join Rooms on (Student.roomid = rooms.roomId)
    Group by HostelCode, RoomId
),
RoomsRemain (
    select HostelCode, roomId, Capacity as Rooms from HostelCapacity 
    union
    select HostelCode, roomId, -Occupied as Rooms from RoomsOccupied
)
select HostelCode, roomId, sum(rooms) from RoomsRemain
where HostelCode = 1
group by HostelCode, roomId
```

При всей кажущейся неэффективности запроса, движок сделает нормальный план и вполне оптимально выполнит запрос как единое целое. Но при этом человеку гораздо легче воспринимать отдельные части запроса. а главное в таком запросе четко выделяются повторно-используемые части запроса, текст которых вы можете использовать в других запросах. А также очень четко выделяются части, которые движок может распаралеллить.

Answer (score 0):

Довольно глупый но работающий пример.

```
declare @HostCode int = 1;
Select  Sum(Rooms.Capacity)-(Select COUNT(*)
    From Student inner join Rooms on Rooms.RoomId=Student.StudentId
    inner join Hostel on Hostel.HostelCode=Rooms.HostelCode
    Where Hostel.HostelCode Like @HostCode)
 AS Rooms
From Rooms
WHERE Rooms.HostelCode Like @HostCode
```

Comment: зачем Like? И зачем джойнить таблицу Hostel? Никакой роли этот join не играет. У вас есть столбец HostelCode в таблице Rooms, сразу же фильтруйте по нему, как указано в моем решении.